# Neo4j + Django: Where do I write the top-level Driver object?

Tags: python, django, neo4j

It is written in [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/1.7/driver.html#object-lifetime) that

> For general applications, it is recommended to create one top-level Driver object that lives for the lifetime of the application.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> from neo4j import GraphDatabase
>
> class Application(object):
>
>     def __init__(self, uri, user, password)
>         self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password))
>
>     def close(self):
>         self.driver.close()
> ```

Where do I write this code?

I want to use neo4j as a database in views.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote it in `views.py` and instantiate the app there. It works.